# How to shift the title down without moving the margin?

Tags: spacing, titles

I use the following code:

```
 \documentclass[letterpaper,MMMyyyy,nonstopmode]{simpleresumecv}
 \newcommand{\CVAuthor}{John Doe}
 \newcommand{\CVTitle}{John Doe's CV for Acme Corporation}
 \newcommand{\CVNote}{CV compiled on {\today} for Acme Corporation}
 \newcommand{\CVWebpage}{http://www.example.com/~johndoe}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhf{}
 \rhead{blah blah}
 \lhead{blah blah}


  \hypersetup{
  pdftitle={\CVTitle},
  pdfauthor={\CVAuthor},
  pdfsubject={\CVWebpage},
  pdfcreator={XeLaTeX},
  pdfproducer={},
  pdfkeywords={},
  unicode=true,
  bookmarks=true,
  bookmarksopen=true,
  pdfstartview=FitH,
  pdfpagelayout=OneColumn,
  pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
  hidelinks,
  breaklinks}


 \newcommand{\Code}[1]{\mbox{\textbf{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\CodeCommand}[1]{\mbox{\textbf{\textbackslash{#1}}}}

 \begin{document}
 \Title{\CVAuthor}

 \begin{Body}

  \Section
  {Education}
  {Education}
  {PDF:Education}


  \end{Body}


  \UseNoteFont%
  \null\hfill%
  [\textit{\CVNote}]

  \end{document}
```

However the title will overlap with the top margin, how can I rectify it?

Comment: Could you please also provide the document class (and make sure that your snippet compiles)?

Comment: A template always has a document class and loads packages.

Comment: It should compile now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 top=25mm,
 headsep=10mm
 }
```

Output:

[image]